# Show specific div when atag is click. And hide other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm faily new to jquery and coding in general. I'm having a few troubles with this.

What i want is for when the page loads, the 'Vlogging' link is active and 'Details 1' is shown. Then when you click on either 'Filmmaking' or 'Beme'... 'Details 2 or 3 is shown and which ever one was there goes away.

I have everything set up right so far just need to get it to where when you click on one of the other links the correct 'Details' text shows itself.

Thank you so much and i have it in a fiddle right now!

http://jsfiddle.net/t1huc43d/

Here is the code than needs tuned:

```
$(function() {
   $("togglediv1").click(function() {
      $("#togglediv1").removeClass("display-start");
      $("li").removeClass("display");
      $(this).addClass("display");
   });
});
```

Comment: There are many plugins for implementing tabs in your page.

Comment: THANK YOU ALL SO MUCH! I guess i dont have the reputation to upvote you guy but thank you all. Each of your responses seem to do the job, and have helped me understand it a lot better. Thank you again!

Comment: You don't have to upvote, you just need to mark one as the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code will **save you a lot of time**.  I added a custom attribute called "data".  This attribute is used to tie the link to the tab you wish to display.  This code will make it a lot easier to add additional tabs and etc.  Look at the bottom for the changed HTML and JavaScript.

```
<div id="wrap">

<ul id="divtoggle">
    <li><a class="link" data="1">Vlogging</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" data="2"> Filmmaking</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" data="3"> Beme</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="text">
    <div class="tab" data="1">Details 1</div>
    <div class="tab" data="2">Details 2</div>
    <div class="tab" data="3">Details 3</div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
  $(".link").click(function () {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    dataAttr = $(this).attr("data");
    $(".tab").hide();
    $(".tab[data="+dataAttr+"]").show();
  });
  $(".link:first").click();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
   $("#togglediv1").click(function() {
      $("#one").removeClass("display");
      $("#one").addClass("display-start");
      $("#two").removeClass("display-start");
      $("#two").addClass("display");
      $("#three").removeClass("display-start");
      $("#three").addClass("display");
   });
});

$(function() {
   $("#togglediv2").click(function() {
      $("#one").removeClass("display-start");
      $("#one").addClass("display");
      $("#two").removeClass("display");
      $("#two").addClass("display-start");
      $("#three").addClass("display");
      $("#three").removeClass("display-start");
   });
});
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t1huc43d/3/

Since your ids aren't that conducive in tracking what is clicked and what isn't, I decided to just use `this` to find what you've clicked in correspondence with the details.

Your updated javascript:

```
$(function() {
   $("li").click(function() {
      $("#togglediv1").removeClass("active-start");
      $("li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      let temp = $("#divtoggle").children();
            var index;

      for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
      {
        if (this == temp[i] )
        {
            index = i;
          break;
        }
      }

      $(".display-start").addClass("display");
      $(".display-start").removeClass("display-start");

          let text_children = $(".text").children()
      let the_child = text_children[index];
            $(text_children[index]).addClass("display-start");
      $(text_children[index]).removeClass("display");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery actually has some components to help you out, but to me, the shortest and CLEANEST way of doing this is the following:

The first thing I'd do is set an `id` of each of the titles, incrementing them by 1. Then, I'd do the same for the details like so:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <ul id="divtoggle">
        <li><a class="title" id="title-1">Vlogging</a></li>
        <li><a class="title" id="title-2"> Filmmaking</a></li>
        <li><a class="title" id="title-3"> Beme</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="text">
        <div class='display' id="detail-1">Details 1</div>
        <div class='display' id="detail-2">Details 2</div>
        <div class='display' id="detail-3">Details 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After that, the JQuery is pretty simple. Setup a click event on the class `title`. The first thing to do is to parse the `id` of the clicked title. Once you have that, target the related detail and show it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(".title").click(function() {

     //*** get id
     var id = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
     if (typeof id != "undefined"){

       //*** hide other descriptions and show yours
       $(".display").hide();
       $("#detail-" + id).show();
     }

   });

});
```

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/volikofihe/edit?html,js,console,output**

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Simplified your CSS a little. Toggling a `.active` class on the top links, and a `.display` class on the text divs. When you click on a link, the code uses the `$.index()` of that link in the list as the index of the text div to show. So if you click on the 2nd link, it will show the 2nd text box.

```js
$(function() {
   $toggleLinks = $('#divtoggle a'),
   $displays = $('.text div');
   
   $toggleLinks.on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $toggleLinks.removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
     $displays.removeClass('display');
     $displays.eq($(this).closest('li').index()).addClass('display');
   });
});
```

```css
li {
  color: grey;
  font: effra;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  color: orange;
}

.text div {
  display: none;
}

.text .display {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">

  <ul id="divtoggle">
    <li><a class="active">Vlogging</a></li>
    <li><a>Filmmaking</a></li>
    <li><a>Beme</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="text">
    <div class='display'>Details 1</div>
    <div>Details 2</div>
    <div>Details 3</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Preserved as much of your existing code as possible. [Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sleeyuen/2a88LLmp/1/)

I added a data-controls custom attribute to each of your li elements so as to associate them to each of the corresponding data divs:

```
<li data-controls="one"><a id="togglediv1" class="active-start">Vlogging</a></li>
<li data-controls="two"><a id="togglediv2"> Filmmaking</a></li>
<li data-controls="three"><a id="togglediv3"> Beme</a></li>
```

Then I updated the JavaScript to remove and add the classes, as needed.